# Why do these impossible-looking regexes match these strings?

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

In Perl I have

```
    if ($_ =~ /$search/)
    {
        print STDERR "$search matches $_";
        ...
```

which outputs

```
^[\s\t]*#?[\s\t]*unix_listener[\s\t\]+auth-userdb[\s\t]* matches   unix_listener lmtp {
^[\s\t]*#?[\s\t]*unix_listener[\s\t\]+auth-userdb[\s\t]* matches   unix_listener auth-userdb {
^[\s\t]*#?[\s\t]*unix_listener[\s\t\]+auth-userdb[\s\t]* matches   #unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
^[\s\t]*#?[\s\t]*unix_listener[\s\t\]+auth-userdb[\s\t]* matches   unix_listener dict {
```

This seems impossible since only one of the `$_` strings contains `auth-userdb`

Even weirder, by adding a `\{` to the end of the regex I get

```
^[\s\t]*#?[\s\t]*unix_listener[\s\t\]+auth-userdb[\s\t]*\{ matches   unix_listener lmtp {
```

but no other matches (on the same input).

I thought I understood regexes of this type completely, but I can't figure out the logic here.

Someone please explain

- why the first four `$_` lines match `$search` instead of only the one which contains `auth-userdb`
- why adding the `\{` to the regex eliminated all but one match.

Comment: Hint: `[\s\t\]` may not mean what you think it means.

Comment: As an aside `\s` already contains `\t`.

Comment: And further, `\s` does not belong in a character class.  In other words, just write `\s*` or `\s+`

Comment: @Happy Green Kid Naps, No, `\s` is perfectly fine in a character class. If it was the only thing in the class, then it would make sense to just use `\s`, but that's not the case here.

Comment: This is where a good debugging tool is critical, since it's easy to miss things when you're just eyeballing them. The [`re` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#%27debug%27-mode) is good once you've gotten a grasp on the output syntax; [YAPE::Regex::Explain](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAPE::Regex::Explain) is more beginner-friendly, but only explains the components of the regex (it doesn't explain why a regex matches or doesn't match a particular string). There's also [Regexp::Debugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Debugger), although I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take a look at the character class you wrote:

```
Start                 End
|                       |
v                       v
[\s\t\]+auth-userdb[\s\t]
      ^
      |
      Because this is escaped
```

So you effectively have:

```
[abdeh-u\[\]+\s\t]
```

Replace whole regex with `^\s*#?\s*unix_listener\s+auth-userdb\s*` since `\t` is included within `\s`.